# Is it possible to create the compound table using p:dataTable?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

This is rather conceptual question, I have a compound table to be implemented and I am not sure if I should use `<p:dataTable>` for the same.

The structure is like there will be values for **weekly** basis and depending on those **cumulative values** will have to be calculated which will be part of the same table. Is it possible using `<p:dataTable>`? or I will have to create the structure using panel grids..rows and column..Any suggestions?

**Structure:** (the value are arbitrary for now)
[please see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/009ED.png)

Comment: you can use `<ui:repeat>` for number of strategy (rows) and then inside that `<ui:repeat>` use another `<ui:repeat>` for number of weeks (columns).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See [summary row in showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/summaryRow.xhtml)

Comment: Summary Row solved the problem..! Thank You Vasil Lukach.